# Bool value not changing

Tags: c#

I have this simple code...

```
Public class Form1 : Form {

   //bool value = false;
   bool value;

   public Form1()
   {
        InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
           if (value) {
             MessageBox.Show("ValueChanged");
           }
   }

   private void btn_Click (Object sender, EventArgs e) { 
           value = true;
           MessageBox.Show("btnClicked");
   }
}
```

MessageBox showing when btn_Click is triggered, but not in Form1_Load event?

Iv'e also tried to put the if (value) statement in the Form1 constructor (after the InitializeComponent method) but the bool remains unchanged. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
But what if its not 'resetting' the data?

Comment: You initialize `value` to `false`, so the message box won't show unless you change that somewhere else between the object construction and the form loading.

Comment: Study a bit about programming, and you'll notice that everything has a sequence to it. Much like life, you cannot change something once it's already done.

Comment: The `Load` event happens when the form *loads*. You click the button *after* the form has loaded, so why would you expect the `Load` event to fire again?

Comment: On Form_Load your `value` will be false, as you are changing the value in button click. You need check `value` in any other method.

Comment: Thx, much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

The form constructor and Form_Load code runs before the button click event handler sets the variable to true. If you close the form and create a new instance of it, that instance will have its own field which is again false initially. The code inside the if statement will therefore never be executed.

Comment: Thank you, well put

Answer (score 0):

Simply writing an `if` statement won't "monitor" a value for changes - it just runs when you tell it to.

The following event handler

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       if (value) {
         MessageBox.Show("ValueChanged");
       }
}
```

runs *only* when the form loads. There's absolutely no reason for it to run again simply because `value` changed. Note that that does not mean that `value` isn't changing.

You probably want to read about [C# events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx), which is an implementation of the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). You may also be interested in the [INotifyPropertyChanged interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I know that Controls added in Form1_Load stays in memory and its read within main thread... Form1_Load is triggered only once?

Comment: @JoTheProgrammer It's only triggered when the form is actually loading.